# Как правильно иcпользовать семафоры в программе?

Tags: linux, c, файлы, ос, семафоры

Я только недавно начал разбираться с этой темой и вот наткнулся на проблему:
как правильно в этом коде использовать семафоры, чтобы избежать ошибки (błąd blokowania semafora = ошибка блокировки семафора)?

Я полагаю, что дело просто в том, что главный процесс останавливается на     semlock(semid2) в конце и пытается заблокировать процесс ещё до того, как дочерний процесс завершит работу. Поэтому так выходит. Как исправить, чтобы логика осталась?

Извините за польский, думаю, не критично. Функции-то на английском...

```
#include <unistd.h>     // fork
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <sys/ipc.h>        // ftok
#include <sys/sem.h>        // operacje na semaforach
#include <stdlib.h>     // exit
#include <err.h>            // errx
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHM_SIZE     2560

/* unia dla semafora */
    union semun {
        int val;                                // wartosc dla SETVAL
        struct semid_ds *buf;               // bufor dla IPC_STAT, IPC_SET
        unsigned short int *array;      // tablica dla GETALL, SETALL
        struct seminfo *__buf;          // bufor dla IPC_INFO
    };

/* blokowanie semafora */
int semlock(int semid) {
    
    /* Struktura opisujaca operacje na semaforach */
    struct sembuf opr;  
    /* podgld struktury z opisem pol:
        struct sembuf {
            ushort semnum;
            short sem_op;
            ushort sem_flg;
        };
    * 
    * gdzie:
    *   semnum - numer semafora,
    *   sem_op - operacja na semaforze:
    *       sem_op > 0 - (V) zwiekszenie semafora o wartosc "sem_op"
    *       sem_op < 0 - (P) polozenie semafora (wstrzymanie procesu) 
    *                    lub zmniejszenie semafora o wartosc "sem_op"
    *       sem_op = 0 - (Z) "przejscie pod semaforem", odwrotnosc (P)
    */

    opr.sem_num =  0;
    opr.sem_op  = -1;        // blokowanie
    opr.sem_flg =  0;        // operacja blokujaca
            
    if (semop(semid, &opr, 1) == -1){
        warn("Blad blokowania semafora!");
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


/* odblokowanie semafora */
int semunlock(int semid) {
    
    /* Struktura opisujaca operacje na semaforach */
    struct sembuf opr;  
    
    opr.sem_num = 0;
    opr.sem_op  = 1;
    opr.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semop(semid, &opr, 1) == -1){
        warn("Blad odblokowania semafora!");
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}   

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");   
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    key_t key1, key2;           // klucz dla semaforow
    int   semid1, semid2;   // ID semaforow
    union semun ctl;            // unia do kontroli semafora    
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Tworzymy klucz dla semafora I */
    if ((key1 = ftok(".", 'A')) == -1) 
        errx(1, "Blad tworzenia klucza!");
    
    /* Pobieramy ID semafora. Jesli semafor nie istnieje - tworzymy. */
    /*           semget(klucz, liczba semaforow, flagi/parametry) */
    if ((semid1 = semget(key1, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
        errx(2, "Blad tworzenia semafora!");
    
    /* Inicjujemy semafor I jako podniesiony (S = 1). */
    ctl.val = 1;
    if (semctl(semid1, 0, SETVAL, ctl) == -1)
        errx(3, "Blad ustawiania semafora!");

    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Tworzymy klucz dla semafora II */
    if ((key2 = ftok(".", 'B')) == -1) 
        errx(1, "Blad tworzenia klucza!");
    
    /* Pobieramy ID semafora. Jesli semafor nie istnieje - tworzymy. */
    /*           semget(klucz, liczba semaforow, flagi/parametry) */
    if ((semid2 = semget(key2, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
        errx(2, "Blad tworzenia semafora!");
    
    /* Inicjujemy semafor II jako podniesiony (S = 1). */
    ctl.val = 1;
    if (semctl(semid2, 0, SETVAL, ctl) == -1)
        errx(3, "Blad ustawiania semafora!");
    /*****************************************************************/     
    
    int i;
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm, *s;

    /* Tworzymy klucz dla pamieci dzielonej. */
    if ((key = ftok(".", 'A')) == -1) 
        errx(1, "Blad tworzenia klucza!");

    /* Tworzymy segment pamieci dzielonej */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) 
        errx(2, "Blad tworzenia segmentu pamieci dzielonej!");

    /* Dolaczamy pamiec dzielona do naszej przestrzeni danych. */
    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
        errx(3, "Blad przylaczania pamieci dzielonej!");
 
    /* Blokujemy semafor procesu, ktory nie powinien wystartowac pierwszy */
    semlock(semid1);
       
    /* Wypelniamy pamiec dzielona danymi. */
    s = shm;        
    i = 0;
    while(!feof (fp) && i<2056) {
        if (fread(s , sizeof(char), 2056, fp))
        {
            i += 2056;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    /* Odlaczamy sie od pamieci dzielonej. */
    shmdt(shm); 
    
    semlock(semid2);
    semunlock(semid1);
    /* rozdwajamy proces */
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        /* proces blokuje swoj semafor */
        semlock(semid1);    
        
        /* Dolaczamy pamiec dzielona do naszej przestrzeni danych. */
        if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
        errx(3, "Blad przylaczania pamieci dzielonej!");
        
        /* Odczytujemy zawartosc pamieci dzielonej i wypisujemy na STDOUT.*/
        s = shm;
        for (i = 0; i < SHM_SIZE; i++){
            putchar(*s);
            s++;
        }
        s--;
        putchar('\n');
    
        /* Odlaczamy sie od pamieci dzielonej. */
        shmdt(shm);

        /* Uwaga! Pamiec dzielona jest zwalniana przez SEND, wiec nie 
        * musimy martwic sie o usuwanie jej. */
        
        /* Odblokowujemy semafor drugiemu procesowi */
        semunlock(semid2);
    }
    
    semlock(semid2);
    
    /* Kasujemy segment pamieci dzielonej. */
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    
    semctl(semid1, 0, IPC_RMID, ctl);
    semctl(semid2, 0, IPC_RMID, ctl);
    
    exit(0);
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: По-моему на польском там хорошие комментарии написаны. Это вы их писали?

Comment: Как раз таки комментарии писал не я, а преподаватель, но я тоже мог бы...

Comment: библиотека и функции семафоров незнакомы. написали-бы полный код и `include` чтобы смогли проверить.

Comment: Написал. Просто здесь иногда попадаются люди, которые закидывают за то, что минимальный код не приводишь.

Comment: @Алексей, добавьте печати, чтобы было сразу понятно в каком месте выдаются сообщения. Если я правильно понял, текст, начинающийся с "`./lab_11 ./txt ...`" и заканчивающийся "`...555555`", печатает код потомка (это содержимое файла, переданного в `argv[1]`). А вот откуда (lock/unlock child/parent ???) `warn()` виводит сообщения "`lab_11: Blad blokowania ...`" не понятно.

Comment: ./lab_11 ./txt  -  это я вызываю программу с параметром. Текст начинается с "sssssssssss..." и заканчивается "...555555". Я анализировал его отладчиком и результат такой: ошибку выводит последний semlock(semid2); после fork'a. Я так полагаю, что тут родительский процесс просто обгоняет дочерний процесс и пытается по новой заблокировать semid2. Просто, вот как покрасивее сделать-то?)

Comment: @Алексей, мне кажется, что child  процесс (по логике вещей) должен завершаться внутри `if (fork() == 0) { ... }`. Если так, то просто завершите этот `if() { ... }` вызовом `exit(0);`

Comment: Ха! Это помогло. А в чём собственно суть? Просто процесс дочерний и так завершался автоматически в конце программы.

Comment: Он делал не нужные вызовы (т.е. то, что в конце своей работы (весь код после if) делает родительский процесс, он повторял, очевидно, что не все из этого правильно).

Comment: @avp, Спасибо...

Comment: @Алексей, успехов в учебе!