# Почему не удаляет очередь?

Tags: linux, c, ос, обработка-сигналов

Я только недавно начал разбираться с темой очередей сообщений и вот наткнулся на проблему, связанную с обработкой сигналов:
почему во время обработки сигнала SIGRTMIN+1 родительский процесс не удаляет очередь qid?

Извините за польский, думаю, не критично. Функции-то на английском...

```
...

int remove_queue( int qid ){
    if( msgctl( qid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1)
        return(-1);
          
    return(0);
}

...

void p_S (int signal){
        
        remove_queue(qid);
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL); 
        
        return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    
    int sig;
        
    sigset_t mask_set, old_mask;
    sigfillset(&mask_set);
    sigdelset(&mask_set, SIGRTMIN+1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_set, &old_mask);
    
    signal(SIGRTMIN+1, p_S);
    
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");   
    
    key_t  msgkey;
  
    /* tworzymy wartość klucza IPC */
    msgkey = ftok(".", 'm');
  
    /* otwieramy/tworzymy kolejkę */
    if(( qid = open_queue( msgkey)) == -1) {
        perror("Otwieranie_kolejki");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    msg.mtype   = 1;        /* typ wiadomości musi być dodatni */  
     
    int i =0 ; 
    while(!feof (fp) && i<N) {
        if (fread(msg.string , sizeof(char), N, fp))
        {
            i += N;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    /* Wysylamy */
    if((send_message( qid, &msg )) == -1) {
        perror("Wysylanie");
        exit(1);
    }
            
    /* rozdwajamy proces */
    if(fork())
    {
        sigset_t mask_set, old_mask;
        sigfillset(&mask_set);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_set, &old_mask);
        
        /* Odbieramy */
        buf.mtype   = 1;        /* typ wiadomości musi być dodatni */
        
        /* Odbieramy wiadomosc */
        read_message(qid, buf.mtype, &buf);
        printf("Zawartosc: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)                           
        printf("%c", buf.string[i]);
        getchar();            
        kill(getppid(), SIGRTMIN+1);

    }
    
    sigwait (&mask_set, &sig);  
        
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: И что именно сообщает в `errno` вызов `msgctl()`?

Comment: Не могу прочитать, программа сразу прекращает свою работу. Пробовал использовать sleep, пробовал убирать return(0) и return(-1), убирать kill(getpid(), SIGKILL) - всё равно прекращается работа программы.

Comment: В подобном случае надо сразу после `if( msgctl( qid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1)` вызвать `perror()` (до `return -1;`)

Comment: Попробовал - не реагирует. Самое интересное, что если вызвать функцию 
        remove_queue(qid) в дочернем процессе, то всё работает.

Comment: Тогда у вас `p_S (int signal)` скорее всего вообще не вызывается. Наверное вам надо поставить всюду побольше печати (или запустить под отладчиком) и твердо убедиться по какому пути исполняется программа

Comment: Верно, не входит. А видимых причин нету...

Comment: imho `kill(getppid(), SIGRTMIN+1);` вот причина (посылаете сигнал не тому процессу)

Comment: Так я проверял pid'ы и всё в порядке. Посылал вручную - всё тоже самое.

Comment: Странно. Или мы имеем дело с *разным кодм*? У вас написано `if(fork()) { ... kill(getppid(), SIGRTMIN+1);..}` т.е. сигнал вы посылаете в родителе к его родителю

Comment: Проблема решена. Всё моя невнимательность: конечно же, надо if(fork() == 0). Спасибо!

Comment: Может поможете мне с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371200/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2434965_1371200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял логику Вашей программы, код, который начинается строками

```
/* rozdwajamy proces */
if(fork())
```

должен выполняться в **дочернем** процессе. Это по логике... А на самом деле,
ненулевое значение (pid порождённого процесса) *fork()* возвращает в **родительском** процессе. Поэтому этот кусок кода выполняется в родительском процессе, что разрушает логику работы программы.

Comment: Нам этого никто не объяснял. А как исправить лучше всего?

Comment: @Алексей Что бы этот код исполнялся в дочернем процессе, просто запишите этот оператор так: *if(fork() == 0)*.  Но настоятельно советую прочитать хотя бы это: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_parallel/node7.html Обратите внимание, как организуется работа с системным вызовом *fork()*

Comment: Я в принципе всегда так и писал. Но потом, почему-то, начал упускать этот момент.

Comment: Проблема решена. Всё моя невнимательность. Спасибо!

Comment: Может, поможете мне с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371200/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2434965_1371200